# Glamour fuel injector repair

Tags: fuel-system, maintenance, repair

My Glamour FI bike flooded and was fully covered with water. After drying my bike, I changed engine oil, air filter, and cleaned the silencer and petrol tank. After that, I switched on the bike using the key, then my FI indication was not blinking. What is the issue? What can i do?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  It sounds like this might be an electrical issue -- water's not so good for those electronics.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to mind, both might result from the bike being "fully covered with water." Both would arise from water in the wrong places.

First, when fully submerged in water, the battery might have discharged because the water made an electrical connection between the + and the - connectors. This discharge may, in addition, have damaged the battery so that it cannot now be charged. In any event, ascertain if the battery is charged; if not, charge it; and if it cannot be made to hold a charge, replace it. And even with a new and good battery, the bike may not run because of the matters discussed in the second paragraph, below.

Second, also when fully submerged, the bike's electrical system will have be completely covered with water. It's very likely that internal pieces of the electrical system (switches, relays, wires and connectors, the generator or alternator and voltage regulator, etc) are still full of water and not operating as they should. Further, components that are supposed to be electrically independent of other components may now be wrongly connected because water, even a little, will allow an electrical path between them.  You will have to disassemble and check, clean, and dry *all* the components of the bike's electrical system, as well as the spaces between them that might contain moisture.